# date Formatter in j2me?

Tags: date, java-me, time

I'm giving the input as `milliseconds` and I'm getting output as `Sat Aug 13 14:00:00 GMT+05:30 2011`

Eg:

```
 Date resultdate = new Date(1313224200000L);
 System.out.println("Date: " + resultdate);
```

How will you format this date as 13-08-2011  and time as 14:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following methods for same,

```
public static String getDate(long currentTimeMillis)
{
    Date today = new Date(currentTimeMillis);
    DateField date = new DateField( "", DateField.DATE_TIME, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30") );
    date.setDate(today);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(today);

    String dateStr = "" + getTwoDigitStr(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)) + "-" + getTwoDigitStr(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    return dateStr;
}

public static String getTime (long currentTimeMillis )
{
    Date today = new Date(currentTimeMillis);
    DateField date = new DateField ( "", DateField.TIME, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT +5:30")  );
    date.setDate(today);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(today);

    String timeStr = "" + cal.get( Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
    return timeStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man It works good...How Can I change into 24Hrs Format?

Comment: Its very easy process, first try your self. else i will tell you later on.

Comment: It should return you time in 24Hrs, here it is working fine, just check your phone settings.